# How to see if a table is empty?

Tags: t-sql, agent

Currently there is an excel file being copied from one dir to another using Copy-Item

Sometimes the excel file is blank, i.e. the table inside of it has columns but no actual data. How might I enter a t-sql job step before the copy-item step to say:

```
if excel file = blank, don't move to directory (or quit job), else move to directory (go to next step)
```

or something to that effect? So far I've tried using IF(EXISTS and also variations of SELECT 1 FROM TABLE in tandem but not getting the desired results.

Answer (score 0):

Once you mount the excel file, you can do a SELECT COUNT(0) FROM TABLE and the check the value if it equals 0.